# How can I change the color of all text colored in (for example) blue in a Google Presentation slides?

Tags: google-drive, google-slides

How can I change the color of all text colored in (for example) blue in a Google Presentation slides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Slides currently doesn't have a feature to change the color of all text colored in (for example) blue in a Google Presentation slides. One could however write a Google Apps Script to achieve that. See  https://developers.google.com/slides/quickstart/apps-script for the documentation.